# Login from a site A to a site B?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization

There's one news-portal and its huge (site A). During production backwards, it has been even powered with some sort of a social networking stuff - not yet started, but about to start (soon site B).

Packed together looks great, but in some future there might be a lot of problems with maintaining the database, servers and stuff so I've been asked to separate it as I did. Site A goes on its own domain, site B also - databases are separated.

Now, I need to do the following: when user logs into site B (social site) and arrives to site A (portal) they should be instantly logged in there too (on a site A).

Any ideas how to do this - without duplicating entries to user tables?

**EDIT:**

Any other ideas instead of auth services? OpenId will just give us one user with 10 accounts, fakes and so on. How about cookie stuff or multi-database queries?

**EDIT 2:**

Well this is something hot.. unless its not April 1st joke and worth a try:
http://www.shawnhogan.com/2005/12/cross-database-join-with-mysql.html

Comment: create the user in both DBs on register.

Comment: Look into SSO with services such as CAS or OAuth that allows you to share logins between websites.  Basically you'll have a single authoring source for usernames and passwords that both websites can rely up on for their authing needs.  They'll pass credentials to the service and the service can either allow or deny them.

Comment: @FrederickBehrends I would recommend against that.  it is a nightmare to manage from a database perspective.  It creates a bunch of redundant data.

Comment: @ Frederick Yea crossed my mind but I'm trying to avoid that if possible.. simply because there might be a site C also. In that case i would rather stuck to just one DB, but again I cant :s

Comment: seeing that they're both totally different (domain and database), and one of them should vouch for the other - that's what OpenID does (unless you want to reinvent OpenID, be my guest)

Comment: See my answer here bellow. You're right, but if this answer bellow works (just found it, tested it on xammp and it works), and you have a cluster of 2-3 servers.. from a point of theory, thats a go! DBs can be separated, domains also. Of course, sites should be resident on 1 server /or cluster exclusively what is more then enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9844134/472495) is of any use.

It's pretty simple, and only requires user information to be kept on one side. Where you need some information on the non-database side, you can just pass that information there using values in a query string, alongside the encrypted string.

Comment: Yes thats great I intend to use it for some stuff for sure in this project. Thanx Halfer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `OpenID`.

OpenID is an open standard that describes how users can be authenticated in a decentralized manner, eliminating the need for services to provide their own ad hoc systems and allowing users to consolidate their digital identities.

If you want to share some profile information (e.g. posts or photos) without giving access to your login and password you can use `OAuth`.

Answer (score -2):

Can you believe this?

```
$DB->query("SELECT * FROM table..."); // works of course...

$DB->query("SELECT * FROM another_database.table..."); // WORKS ALSO!
```

This guy is a miracle:

http://www.shawnhogan.com/2005/12/cross-database-join-with-mysql.html

I don't believe it, so simple at the end!

Comment: Ah, I thought by "DBs are separated" you meant they were on different servers, and that a firewall would prevent this connection (database servers are usually firewalled so that only selected web servers can access them). But if you are able to connect to the first database server from the second website, you don't even need a cross-database join - just use two sets of credentials. One set for the second site's own database, and another set for the first database.

Comment: @Mike - Haha Mike why not?????:D at-Halfer Server/cluster is not separated, but even better if it could be - if there is solution for it - and yes that is question about. I like/d your answer really but I'm to tired few days now to get it tested/done. But (hidden) intercommunication of servers - yeah, thats what this question is about.