# Best way to securely set a session cookie on another domain

Tags: php, security, cookies, hash

We currently have 2 sites `http://www.foo.co.uk` and `https://secure.foo.com`.

The www site does not have an SSL certificate and is on a different domain.

We have a login button on `http://www.foo.co.uk` that when clicked opens up an iframe of `https://secure.foo.com` with a form, when the user logs in it creates a session cookie on that domain (`foo.com`).

The session cookie then needs to be copied to `foo.co.uk` so what it does is redirects you to `http://www.foo.co.uk/setcookie.php?session=abcd1234` which allows us to set the same cookie on the origin domain.

This is not a very secure solution so I have been looking into how to make this better - the best idea I have found is to send a hash using something like `hash_hmac` along with the params to the setcookie.php script and then verify it on the other end before creating the cookie.

Whilst this is better it doesn't prevent man in the middle attacks. Bearing in mind that www is not SSL secured I don't think you can prevent this completely, so the next best thing would be to include a timestamp in the hash to make it valid for 5 minutes.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can make this better, or point out any pitfalls with this approach? I would be most grateful.

Comment: You might try this at security.stackexchange.com.  There are a lot of bright people here and you'll likely get good answers here, but from a pure security standpoint, they may thing of things we wouldn't.  My gut tells me there **is** no good way to set a session cookie at another domain, and that the right thing to do is change the business rules so it's not necessary.  But that's just a gut reaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a shared secret between your 2 domains, and use a symmetric encryption algorithm to encrypt the cookie value, or set a public/private key in the insecure domain and make the secure domain to crypt the cookie using the public key of the insecure domain.

Also, bear in mind that encrypting the login process but transferring afterwards the session cookie over an insecure channel might allow an attacker to impersonate your users (see the [firesheep](http://codebutler.com/firesheep) Firefox extension for more information).

Comment: Yes. If you combine this with a rounded timestamp, it's reasonably insulated from replay attacks as well. I've mentioned [something similar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9844134/472495) before - so long as domain A can prove who it is to domain B, then domain B may safely set a cookie of A's choosing.