# Logon securely over cleartext using PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, curl, mediawiki, password-protection

I am using the Mediawiki API to create accounts on my server #1, and when the account is created I want to automatically login to the Mediawiki that is installed on a different server #2.

Server #2 has a script on there to accept username and password in a query string and automatically login to the Mediawiki that is installed on it.

How can I pass the credentials from Server #1 to Server #2 without compromising security info?

```
$postfield = "action=login&lgname=user&lgpassword=pass&lgtoken={$token}&format=json";
$url = "http://wiki.sign.com/api.php"; // url to wiki's api
```

Comment: SSL would do it - is that a possibility?

Comment: dont have that installed.  needs to be the most basic solution

Comment: There may be a plugin (or you could write one) that uses hashing and a timestamp to implement basic SSO. See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9844134/472495) for basic strategy.

Comment: thats a decent solution.. ill consider that one. thank you

Comment: @halfer: it is generally not a good idea to try and come up with your own encryption scheme. E.g. if you want to authenticate a message (as in the question you linked), use HMAC; that way, you won't be vulnerable to length extension attacks. In this case though, I don't see how it would work at all - you need the cleartext password on server2 for logging in, and you cannot recover it from a hash.

Comment: @Tgr: yes to the first point, no to the second. In the case of the second point (logging onto the remote MediaWiki, or any authenticated system), one would write a plugin to authenticate as a named user, setting the appropriate cookies, without involving the password at all. I should think one can look at the authentication system of MW and do whatever that does, skipping the bit that requires the actual password.

Answer (score 1):

Use symmetric encryption (AES, for example): one server encrypts the API parameters with a secret key, sends the encrypted string, the other server decrypts them with the same key.