# Method for common Single Sign On (SSO) for Yii and core PHP Projects

Tags: php, yii, single-sign-on

I have two projects, one developed in YII and another developed in core PHP. I got the best way to solve it using

https://simplesamlphp.org/

But I don't have access to the server where my project are hosted because I need to setup SimpleSAMLphp on my server. So I am searching for alternatives and I got another way but I am only able to implement that only if both projects are on Yii:

http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/135/single-sign-on-across-multiple-subdomains

I have tried some others too but unsuccessfully, so please help in my problem with best solution. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can create your own using a hash, a shared secret between servers and a timestamp. I briefly [outlined an algorithm here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9844134/472495).

Comment: @halfer it's good idea and i asked with my client but he told me use certified way like simplesamlphp. Thank you for your advice, if you have any other alternative please provide me.

Comment: I got the exact answer and solved the problem myself, if you want to know the answer please inform me. halfer, Samuel Liew, Sergiu Paraschiv, Clockwork-Muse, brandizzi please open this to answer. So that I can provide my logic.