# How to secure Ajax link requests?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Imagine the next scenario: a user wants to register to a webpage and fills a form. While he is filling the form, jQuery keeps checking through a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) if fields are valid, etc...

Taking the email as the primary key which the user will use after registering to login, the email field needs to be checked with [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) to let the user know if that email is registered or not. I want to check it with Ajax to avoid sending the full form and emptying it, refreshing page, etc...

So, when the user has ended filling the email field, the Ajax request is sent to the server, something like the next link:

```
example.com/check.php?email=abcdefg@gmail.com
```

When check.php receives the email, it asks the database if it exists or not and returns a message like: `User already exists` if user exists or `null` if user does not exist.

**The question is:** if someone digs through my .js and finds out links similar to that, they could use that link to send a large number of requests to find out if those random emails exist. This could lead to heavy use of the database or in the worst cases even crashing and private information leaks.

Someone could do a huge for loop to check emails like:

```
//Getting the response of the next links
example.com/check.php?email=aaaaaaa@gmail.com // Returns null
example.com/check.php?email=aaaaaab@gmail.com // Returns null
example.com/check.php?email=aaaaaac@gmail.com // Returns null
example.com/check.php?email=aaaaaad@gmail.com // Returns User already exists
```

**------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

**Since i last accepted the answer, i kept investigating this and found the solution to avoid this behaviour. The following code is for JAVA but the logic can be applied to any other server-side language.**

Before doing ANY ajax request to the server, I request a token to the server. This token looks like this `fmf5p81m6e56n4va3nkfu2ns8n` it is made by a simple method, it can, however, be more complex, but this is good to go.

```
public String getToken() throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    return new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32);
}
```

When requesting the token, the server does not only return the token, but also a small script that in case someone uses browser to inspect element (and browser navbar) and such the script will run and the token will be cleared. Servlet returns something like this:

```
_html += "<head>"
    + "<script> "
    + "window.onload=function(){\n"
    + "       document.body.innerHTML = \"\";\n"
    + "    }"
    + "window.location.href='http://mywebsite.com' "
    + "</script>"
    + "</head>"
    + "<body>"
    + "[" + token+ "]"
    + "</body>"
    + "</html>";
```

First empties the body then navigates back to wherever we want. javascript/jquery will however, catch the entire content as string, then I simply extract the string between [ and ]. This token is only available for the next request, so every AJAX request will have its unique token. On the 2nd reques the token just used is deleted.

After I get the token I append it as parameter to whatever link i request, something like this:

```
ajaxRequestObjet = $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8084/mywebsite.com/servlet", //<-- local tomcat server
    method: "POST",
    data: "type=AJAX&page=some-article&token=fmf5p81m6e56n4va3nkfu2ns8n"
});
```

This method works fine against someone who inspects the website manually and try to use the links, but what about java/php/IIS servers that do this automaticly?

For this ask for header! Something like this:

```
boolean isAjax = "XMLHttpRequest".equals(request.getHeader("X-Requested-With"));
```

It will be true only and only if XMLHttpRequest exists....

There is one last thing to keep in mind. Make sure `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is NOT present in your app` to make sure that any javascript NOT in your server wont get the server resources. If this header does not exist, chrome will return this:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8084/mywebsite.com/servlet. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Java server was in tomcat and I had another apache for this tests, this is the small html present in apache which gave the error above:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
    ajaxRequestObjet = $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8084/mywebsite.com/servlet",
        method: "POST",
        data: "type=AJAX&page=Token"
    });

    ajaxRequestObjet.done(function (msg) { 
        alert(msg);
    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You rate limit them (usually per session, or per client IP) on the server, so that they can only perform `X` checks per second/ minute.

Comment: Your script could sleep an amount of time before doing the database interrogation..

Comment: A sleep delay alone wont do nothing apart from annoy the user with slow performance. The person sniffing the server would simply script this and come back and check it in a few days to see what was found.

Comment: can use session in check.php to count requests ... after n attempt you can track reasons...

Comment: Anyone can spoof headers, so you cannot trust them to determine if the request was sent by a browser.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While you can not control this 100%... there are a few options..

Try using the same methods that people use with Captcha scripts..

Basically when the user loads the form / page.. You generate a random string/id in their PHP session and store it.. When they send the ajax requests, have your ajax check also append the string/id and require it before allowing a check to perform else return a header of 500 or something..

Using this approach with sessions, you could set a allowed limit of checks (say 5) and once the user has tried more than 5 checks, They are required to reload the page or perform a human check (eg Captcha).. Then it resets their count.. Even allow a total of say 30 within 1 hour / per IP or something.

Also use smart events to trigger when the ajax check is done, eg field/tab change or on a button press.. Or when a valid email is detected.. but say .com.au would trigger twice.

Basically this way, even if someone sniffed your JS files and tried to automate the email checker.. It would require them finding a way to append the string/id that you generate and also limit their amount of requests performed.

Beyond this, there is not to much more you can do easily.. But there are still a few other idea's.

Most of them would work around using a PHP session / cookie.. Say for example if they check and find 3 email addresses.. Then again you set that as a limit and force them to require a manual submission or something.

See how the above suggestion goes for you, any questions do feel free to ask. But may take me a day or two to reply as weekend.. Also research how Captcha scripts work as plenty of source code for them.. As they work on the same idea.

**Time Delays** will simply look bad / make your site appear slow / bug the user with waiting for a response.

You need to limit the amount of look up's per session / ip address.. Otherwise there is always a way to get past these checks.. Basically once they hit a limit.. Force the user/ip/session to wait a few minutes/hours and verify them with a Captcha script so it can not be scripted...

**Javascript Security / Hiding The Source**

While you can not do this truly, you can do certain things generate the JS using a PHP page with a JS header.. so `<script src='myjscode.php'></script>` and this allows PHP to check for a valid session.. So stops external requests to an extent.. But this is mostly useful for allowing JS to be only available behind a membership/login..

**Multiple Checks / If Possible In This Case**

Depending on your approach, is this for a user to check if they already have an account? If so.. you could combine the email check with something like their name/country/age/dob ... So they would need to select two or three correct matching values before being able to get a check/response from the ajax call?

Maybe not in your case, but just thought would add this as well.

Comment: Don't try to enforce a limit with a session. A limit per session (in the cookie) is easily circumvented (just delete the cookie).

Comment: Yes of course, But this is just the same as opening and closing the browser as well. Its not a fix, but another method of control. Anyone can clear a session easily.. But its using a combination of methods that is suggested here.

Comment: @Mayhem after long time i found the solution :D your answer was usefull to get there. PD: updated question with my working solution.

Comment: Another way that can help is to check the referrer. However, as the other methods,  it's possible to fake the referrer.

Answer (score 11):

The JavaScript code on your website is executed on the computer of the user, so there is no way you could stop him from digging through your code. Even if you use a code obfuscator (for example, https://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/), the hacker could debug your application and record all requests send to the server.

Everything security-relevant has to happen on the server. You could limit the amount of requests from a specific IP address.

Comment: yeah, even with http://jsbeautifier.org/ you can clean the code and search for links...

Comment: Or use a proxy (ie: fiddlr) to see the AJAX requests

Comment: +1 for telling "Everything security-relevant has to happen on the server", this is certainly the most important thing to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3):

You could protect against brute force attacks with something similar to [CSRF tokens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery#Synchronizer_token_pattern):

Assign a server-generated ID to every client session. Each request to `check.php` should include this ID.

`check.php` should reject requests that do not include an ID, or include an ID that the server did not generate (to prevent attacks with spoofed IDs). It should also rate limit on ID - if a given ID has made a request in (say) the last second, or a given ID makes more than `n` requests in a 10 second interval, it should return an error response. This protects against requests from a single session arriving from several IP addresses.

You should also rate limit by IP address to prevent brute-forcing by opening a large number of web application sessions.

There isn't much you can do to prevent an attacker looking up a single, or small number, of specific email addresses - it's an inherent risk with this type of validation.

Answer (score 3):

One approach to resolve this problem could be this:

Suppose you have ajax request calling your server to receive a response from a particular user or client. You can have a table in your database where you provide a unique token for every user or hash value that can be checked every time user makes an ajax request to the server. If the token value matches the user request value than he is a genuine user. You can also record his number of request on the table to ensure he is making legitimate requests. I acknowledge the fact that it may slow down your app performance, but it will be safe option to consider. Note: you need to retrieve the token on your HTML page to send it with ajax.

Please comment to know more. I have been using this approach and there is no problem until now.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This type of attack can be treated the same as any other brute force attack, where the only effective solution is to use a [Captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA). But of course, Captchas are a detriment to UX, so you have to consider if the additional security is worth it, especially for an attack that is very unlikely to happen anyway. That said, you may want to use a Captcha on your registration form anyway, to prevent bots from creating accounts.

This sort of attack has a huge cost for little reward for the attacker. There are billions of possible email addresses to test for. It could only be worth going to great lengths such as this, if the site in question was particularly sensitive, such as some kind of adult site, where the attacker hopes to blackmail users that he finds.

**CloudFlare**

Not as good as a Captcha solution but the brute force attack might be detected and prevented by CloudFlare's [DDoS](http://[DoS][3]) system. Also, CF can force Tor users to solve a Captcha before accessing your site, which would prevent an attacker from using Tor as a vehicle for the attack.

**IP Rate Limiting**

Rate limiting on an IP basis has problems because if an attacker decided to undertake a task as huge as this, he will likely be using a [Botnet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Botnet) or some other system of multiple machines to launch the attack.

Consider a large organisation such as a University, where all users share the public IP. One of the users launches an attack on your site, and you block his IP, and in the processes blocking everyone else. This countermeasure could actually be used to launch a [DoS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) attack.

**Session ID/CRSF Token**

Definitely not a solution because the attacker needs to simply make a request to the page first, to obtain the token. It's an additional request to make but only an inconvenience for the attacker.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I'd URL-encode the mail-address. `'example.com/check.php?email=' . urlencode(abcdefg@gmail.com)`

Ad your question: when check.php is called, you can

- check, if the user's session and his IP have sent a request during the last seconds
- if not, write the user's session, the user's IP plus the current timestamp to a helper-table plus to a cookie and hit your DB
- if yes, block the request

But I'm afraid this won't help you from fraud because everyone can check your JavaScript and if someone want's to exploit this, he will find ways.

Comment: This answer is incomplete, you are saying 'Just check in  your check.php file if the ipaaddress has senta  request in the last second'. That is a comment not an answer.

Answer (score -1):

check.php should depending on the setup either only be accessible internally, or verify from where the connection is made. Take a look at this previous question- I hope it might be what you're looking for. [how to verify the requesting server in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9843982/how-to-verify-the-requesting-server-in-php)

Comment: This does not really help, i could build a simply console based script that can be run from the browser which will pass a local check.. This would only stop people accessing check.php directly. Not from having the webpage performing the check.

Comment: Yeah, it only solves part of the authentication check. Put bot prevention on the page where people enter the email-address?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `CSRF token` and exit early from your script if you detect that no or an invalid `CSRF token`. Almost (if not all) PHP frameworks come with support for this.

Also check this question from the security community: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/23371/csrf-protection-with-custom-headers-and-without-validating-token

Comment: This doesn't protect you from a hacker executing the requests with curl or something like that.

Comment: Yes, you won't be able to disallow anyone to make requests to your server, but you will reduce the time spent in handling the request if you detect an invalid one. DOS attacks are hard to avoid anyhow.

Comment: @JohannesReuter: a CSRF token could not be forged by the cracker using cURL.

Comment: A CSRF token can easily be requested using cURL then used to in a DOS attack.